# php как вставить слово между тэгами?

Tags: php

Как вставить между этих тэгов слово через php?

```
$str ="<!-- Embed Scripts  -->***СЮДА СЛОВО***<!-- End Embed -->";
```

Comment: между каких строк?

Comment: А где у вас строка в переменной или может просто в тексте программы или может вообще в базе ?

Comment: А там уже что то стоит или там пусто и на закрывающий тег идущий сразу за открывающим в изначальной строке надо проверять ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str ="<!-- Embed Scripts  --><!-- End Embed -->";
print preg_replace('/<!-- Embed Scripts  -->\K/','СЛОВО',$str);
```

С проверкой на наличие закрывающего тега (идущего сразу за открывающим):

```
preg_replace('/<!-- Embed Scripts  -->\K(?=<!-- End Embed -->)/','СЛОВО',$str);
```

С удалением предыдущего содержимого между тегами:

```
preg_replace('/<!-- Embed Scripts  -->\K.*?(?=<!-- End Embed -->)/s','СЛОВО',$str);
```

Comment: А как быть если там уже есть слово? как его заменить?

Comment: После `\K` во втором варианте добавить `.*?`